# How to remove AxisX grid lines from the chart

Tags: devexpress-wpf

I want to remove Gridlines form Chart to achieve that I have written following code but without success.

```
    <Charts:AxisX ShowMajorGridlines="False">
       <Charts:AxisX.LabelOptions>
                 <Charts:AxisLabelOptions Foreground="White"/>
       </Charts:AxisX.LabelOptions>
    </Charts:AxisX>
```

How to remove gridlines form chart ??

Note: Here I am attaching a sample application along with a screenshot for better understanding please take a moment to review it.

Thanks & regards,
Rudresh Bhatt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove horizontal grid line set AxisY 's ShowMajorGridlines property to false.
Therefore the mark up will be like

```
<Charts:CartesianChart.AxisY>
                <Charts:AxisY ShowMajorGridlines="False" />
</Charts:CartesianChart.AxisY>
```

Thanks

Comment: axisY is not assignable to dxChartOptions.